# Node-red in docker keeps rebooting

Tags: docker, node-red

I did an update on my dockers. Suddenly, node-red did not work anymore.

Update docker:

`docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d`

`docker image prune -f`

Pls. see below:

`uname -a` :

> Linux DietPi 6.1.11-meson64 #23.02.2 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 18 00:07:55 UTC 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

`docker -v` :

> Docker version 24.0.4, build 3713ee1

`cat docker-compose.yml | grep image` :

> image: nodered/node-red:latest

The following errormessage makes node-red restart every few seconds:

`docker logs -f nodered` :

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/mime/index.js:4:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
Failed to start server:
/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/mime/types/standard.js:2
```

As I did it today(14/07/2023), 'latest' implies the version as updates 9 days ago. I assume it to be 3.0.2, but I cannot retrieve that info anywhere.

I'm out of options here. Please help. Thanks!

Edit: Additional information:

```
REPOSITORY         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nodered/node-red   latest    ed58160c5a2e   11 months ago   485MB
```

Fullog output:

```
root@DietPi:~/docker/nodered# docker-compose up 
[+] Running 2/2
⠿ Network nodered_node-red-net  Created 0.2s 
⠿ Container nodered             Created 0.4s 
Attaching to nodered
nodered  | Failed to start server:
nodered  | /usr/src/node-red/node_modules/mime/types/standard.js:2
nodered  |
nodered  |
nodered  |
nodered  | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
nodered  |     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
nodered  |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/module/cjs/loader:1033:15)
nodered  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
nodered  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
nodered  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
nodered  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
nodered  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
nodered  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
nodered  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/mime/index.js:4:27)
nodered  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
nodered exited with code 0
root@DietPi:~/docker/nodered#
```

Comment: What exactly does "I did an update on my dockers." mean? What exactly did you update? Also `nodered/node-red:latest` doesn't really help as that tag floats with each release, we would need to know the hash for the image (`docker images nodered/node-red` should show it)

Comment: I updated the initial description. Pls see my answer there.

Comment: The documentation doesn't imply that `--force-recreate` will pull new versions of the containers, so we still can't be sure what the latest tag maps to (the hash from the command I mentioned earlier will confirm). But the very latest 3.0.2 container starts fine on arm64. The error implies one of the files in the mime project is broken, but without more context from the logs it is again hard to say more.

Comment: The logs as shown is the only thing I can get, unless there's some other way to get more detailed info.

Comment: Please answer the questions I have already asked (the hash of the image) and actually show the context for the error you have listed (please format as code, not a quote), I need to see if there is any other log output first. As I said last time without that there really is nothing more we can help with.

Comment: Done. See initial description.

Comment: OK, so the image is 11months old, so not the latest respin of the 3.0.2 release. This implies that your local copy of the image had been corrupted some way (The error implies a file that is part of the image is corrupted). I suggest you run `docker pull nodered/node-red:latest` as I mentioned in the github issue to re-pull the latest respin and try again.

Comment: Took approx 6 minuted 'starting'. Then got an identical error message.

Comment: The github issue is a better place to debug this than Stack Overflow. Please update with the latest status and give more details about your docker-compose project and what hardware you are running on and we can continue

Comment: I seem to have found the issue. One of the flows uses mqtt. However, the mqtt server (a mosquito Docker in my case) was not running. From the logging (docker-compose up) I saw it was failing as it could not connect. This is a bug IMHO as Node-red should always start up. It should give a warning in stead if a service (Mosquito server in my case) is not available. Thanks for you valuable time and effort!

Comment: That code path should have nothing to do with MQTT, that stack traces is hit long before any MQTT clients world ever start to contect

Comment: You are right - I stopped mqtt (nodered notices with a warning) but keeps on running. Then - I stopped nodered and started again. Full start, with a recurring warning 'Connection faied to broker <url>'. So the issue itself is not solved but now it does not seem to be reproducible anymore. I'll use Github if it re-occurs.